# How can I get the photo data (the blob of contact photo) if I have photo_ids

Tags: android

Can you please tell me how can I get the photo data if I have a list of photo_ids?

I try this:

```
cursor = mResolver.query(Contacts.Photos.CONTENT_URI, null, "_id IN (?)" , new String[] {"458"}, null);
```

But the cursor return null.

Any idea How to troubleshoot?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the static method [`loadContactPhoto`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html#loadContactPhoto) to grab the photo for a contact..

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, 458);
Bitmap contactPhoto = People.loadContactPhoto(_context, uri, R.drawable.unkown_contact, null);
if (null != contactPhoto) {
    /* Your Magic Here */
}
```

Just to note, you will likely want to replace `R.drawable.unkown_contact` with a resource you have for non-existent contact photos as well as replace `_context` with an instance of a Context that you have.

Comment: This method is deprecated since API Level 5. How would I do this on an Android phone above 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

The new api is

```
InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, photo);
```